# Using email level web analytics parameters in account wide footers

Tags: marketing-cloud, web-analytics-connector

I would like to implement a tracking pixel in all my emails, I plan to do this by injecting the pixel in the Account level footer. One of the parameters in my pixel is `campaign`, which I would like to be populated an individual email basis.

Would setting up Web Analytics Connector parameters be available as a personalisation string in my Account footer? If yes, what happens if no value is provided, will the value be blank or will the email fail?

Comment: are you talking about the additional email attributes you set up for each email?

Comment: Yes, the additional email attributes, my understanding is they come from the Web Analytics setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the personalization strings associated with the AdditionalEmailAttribute you want.

[image]

so for instance, if the 'campaign' was stored in Attribute 4, you could have the following in your pixel URL - `http://mypixel.com/pixel2?campaign=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%`

If this value is empty, it will provide an empty string in your URL.

If you want to set a default value, you can change the url to something like `?campaign=%%=v(@campaign)=%%` and set campaign via `IF EMPTY(__AdditionalEmailAttribute4) THEN set @campaign = "myDefaultValue" ELSE SET @campaign = __AdditionalEmailAttribute4 ENDIF`